# Sending data via Bluetooth in Android without permissions

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to send a string less than 1 KB via Bluetooth without permissions. Is there any way to do so in Android?

Comment: Hopefully not. The user deserves the right to know that you are planning on sending data via Bluetooth (and, if needed, pairing with another device).

Answer (score 0):

To send some data with Bluetooth you use BluetoothSocket/BluetoothServerSocket and these require "android.permission.BLUETOOTH".

I'm not aware of a way around this, and as commonsware said, that is a good thing.  Doing pretty much anything with bluetooth requires this permission, and some operations requires bluetooth admin permission.